# Scala in Tomcat 7 - HttpServletRequest.getHeaderNames returns java.util.Collection instead of Enumeration?

Tags: scala, tomcat7, scala-collections

when using Scala with Tomcat 7, HttpServletRequest.getHeaderNames() apparently returns java.util.Collection instead of java.util.Enumeration as [indicated in docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeaderNames%28%29).

Does some implicit conversion happen here?

To be more specific, the following servlet:

```
import java.io._
import javax.servlet._
import javax.servlet.http._

class TomcatScalaExample extends HttpServlet {
    override def doGet (req: HttpServletRequest, res: HttpServletResponse): Unit = {
        val out = res.getWriter()
        out.println(res.getHeaderNames.getClass.getCanonicalName)
        out.close()
    }
}
```

prints following in the browser:

```
java.util.ArrayList
```

while I'd expect something related to java.util.Enumeration.

For the reference, here's the code compiled with -Xprint:typer:

```
   [scalac] package pl.kamituel.tomcatscalaexample {
   [scalac]   import java.io._;
   [scalac]   import javax.servlet._;
   [scalac]   import javax.servlet.http._;
   [scalac]   class TomcatScalaExample extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
   [scalac]     def <init>(): pl.kamituel.tomcatscalaexample.TomcatScalaExample = {
   [scalac]       TomcatScalaExample.super.<init>();
   [scalac]       ()
   [scalac]     };
   [scalac]     override def doGet(req: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, res:     javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse): Unit = {
   [scalac]       val out: java.io.PrintWriter = res.getWriter();
   [scalac]       out.println(res.getHeaderNames().getClass().getCanonicalName());
   [scalac]       out.close()
   [scalac]     }
   [scalac]   }
   [scalac] }
   [scalac]
```